# Prompt user to install/view app on mobile site

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari

Does there exist some kind of plugin or lightweight method of determining whether

A. A user is using a mobile device
  B. The user has a particular app
C. The user does not have a particular app.

And depending on what criteria the user satisfies, display a prompt (modal, overlay, pop-up) that allows the user to view the app (if installed) or to install it (if they do not have it installed).

I realize "A" can be achieved by using media queries but I am not sure how to configure the others.

I've seen this done on many many sites so I know that it is not uncommon (view screenshot). Ideally I just want to implement some quick solution. I'm looking for something similar to "Hello Bar" for mobile only, I suppose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETLHr.png (the prompt at the top of the browser)

---

I ended up finding this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Which is exactly what I was looking for and will work in tandem with the other solutions.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html Based entirely on the useragent JS

Comment: @Nate: You can detect application installations with that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No. But those are based on which os you're using... Not sure you can see the installed apps from a browser. -- You might be able to write to the cache (cookie) from the app then when you hit the browser check the cache if it has x app installed.

Comment: @Nate I didn't see that you detect the apps, but this is a step forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this approach if you really need to know if a user has your app installed.

When your app is installed and first run have it create a cookie. The only thing you have to remember to use is the `CookieSyncManager` because the set Cookies are stored in RAM and not storage, `CookieSyncManager` will sync these two.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context)
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync()
```

Once you've set the cookie you can then read the Cookie with the website, if its there show popup etc. Oh and only show this popup only if its a mobile device: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Android Developer On CookieSyncManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Bolg Post Explaining the Usage of the CookieSyncManager:
http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/05/using-cookiesyncmanager/

I know how to do this with android not iOS or Windows...

Comment: This will get me where I need to be. Thanks. The only problem I can see is that I'll be unable to create a cookie for users that already have the app installed. But with this approach, I'll at least be able to create a cookie when the user first gets the app. I'll still have to sniff for users who have already installed the app prior to me implementing these changes. 

Again, thanks!

Comment: Well you can always check if the cookie is there when the app starts. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

There's no **standard** way to do this.

See the end of this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/14/url-protocols-application-protocols-and-asynchronous-pluggable-protocols-oh-my.aspx for one mechanism available to JavaScript in IE10.

IE10's Metro environment offers this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/20/connect-your-web-site-to-your-windows-8-app.aspx but I don't think that exists for the mobile browser.

Comment: This would be great if I were using IE 10. It says there is no cross browser compatibility with this method yet either. Thanks for the recommendation, still searching for a solution though